# Looping through pandas table, changing value by condition on other column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iterator

I am currently trying this to change the values of a panda column depending on another columns value. No problem so far but I would like to iterate through both columns in order to set my tables as in the example below:

I have a panda table like this:

```
id  id2
1    0
1    0
1    0
2    0
2    0
2    0
...
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
id  id2
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    2
2    3
...
```

So I somehow have to check the value of the `id` column and depending on it change the values of `id2`. So far I only have that:

```
n=1
m=50
df.loc[df.id==n, 'id2'] = m
```

This gives me the following output, but is not quite what I am trying to do:

```
 id  id2
 1   50
 1   50
 1   50
 2   50
 2   50
 2   50
```

I am new to programming and all the loops I tried failed. I would be very thankful if anyone could explain me how to do it!

Comment: If you use `.loc` then it should be ok. I do not understand the output is not as desired. How did you do? Loop by `n` i.e range(10)? Did you change value of `m`? Because if you don't then each time you loop, the corresponding `n` will be changed, but to same `50`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cumsum() with groupby()

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'id2':[0,0,0,0,0,0]})

df['id2'] =1
df['id2'] = df.groupby('id')['id2'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id  id2
0   1    1
1   1    2
2   1    3
3   2    1
4   2    2
5   2    3
```

Comment: thanks a lot that was just what i was searching for!

Comment: is there a way to start with 0 and not with 1?

Comment: @Mauritius you can use `add(-1)`  like `df['id2'] = df.groupby('id')['id2'].cumsum().add(-1)`

Answer (score 2):

maybe `DataFrame.rank()` method is which you needed.

examples:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],'id2':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
df['dummy_rank'] = df['id2'].groupby(df['id1']).rank(method='first').apply(int)
```

the key point is 'method' argument, u can learn more info with document pandas.